# Wordpress login not working

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, authentication

When I login to my wordpress admin, this error message displaying

[image]

And when I give username and password, after submit page become blank.

I print out cookies it is displaying `Array ( [PHPSESSID] => 299ttqupf15pinkaomn4003e01 [_ga] => GA1.2.1761213165.1417428531 [_gat] => 1 )`

Comment: And what the linked documentation said?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Cookies, But I check my on difference systems same error message is everywhere.

Comment: Comment out the following statement from login widget `<input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1" />` More details can be found [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cookies-are-blocked-or-not-supported-by-your-browser-1)

Comment: you have install any cache plugin . plugin name?

Comment: I don't use any cache plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

renaming the plugin folder can solve this issue ..please review this https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/27974#ticket

Answer (score 1):

In this case, if you are a programmer, debug the wp-login.php file with print_r($_COOKIE) and check what is going wrong with your cookies. Hope it will help you.

Comment: I print out cookies it display this, Array ( [PHPSESSID] => 299ttqupf15pinkaomn4003e01 [_ga] => GA1.2.1761213165.1417428531 [_gat] => 1 )

Comment: in your wp-login.php comment out this if ( empty( $_COOKIE[ LOGGED_IN_COOKIE ] ) ) condition, approx on line 772 and check what happens. I cant give you exact solution because i can't generate this error manually.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a problem BEFORE the cookie is sent, raising a warning "headers already sent", maybe a plugin issue, you should enable error reporting in your php.ini or .htaccess file (depending on your server's configuration):

```
error_reporting E_ALL 
display_errors On
```

Comment: When I add error_reporting E_ALL 
display_errors On in .htaccess file, after refresh page become blank.

Comment: did you add php_flag in front of these directives ?